# Android Fragment and getWindow()

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public class AircraftFragmentTab extends Fragment{
      private String ac;
      
      public AircraftFragmentTab(String AC){
          ac = AC;
         
      }
         @Override
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState)
         {
             View aircraftView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.acdetails, container, false);
             
             ??? getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
              WebView wv = (WebView) aircraftView.findViewById(R.id.webac);
              wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
              wv.loadUrl("http://ABCD/ACInfo.aspx?AC=" + ac);
              
             return aircraftView;
         }
}
```

I am using a webView and class extends from Fragment. How can I use `getWindow()` here  ?

Comment: Thanks!! It did get rid of the error. But looks like it's not returning any view

Answer (score 115, accepted):

you can use `getActivity().getWindow()`
this `getActivity()` will Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

Comment: This appears to not get the fragment's window if the fragment is displayed in a separate window than the activity.

Answer (score 9):

Example from `Activity`

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
```

Example from `Fragment`

```
requireActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
```